# OpenGL revert all transformation done by a transformation matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, mouseover, transformation

i would like to aplly a reverse transformation matrix in a point. 
What is it for?:
 My app (game) apply transformation into several squares objects, each one has its own transformation matrix that are applyied when drawing it.

But i need to know if the mouse are over each object. so , for each object, I get the mouse position, and try to apply all transformations reversed. to revert the square and the mouseposition to its origin.

If im right, this way i can compare the transformed mouse position with the object bouds.

thw question is.. :how can i apply this reverse transformations ?
i tried the inverse matrix, but it dosent exists all the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no inverse for a transformation matrix (highly unlikely for most common transformations), then there is *no way* to undo the transformation. That's what having no inverse means: that the transformation is one-way.

Also, the way this is generally done is not by transforming mouse coordinates into world-space, but by transforming objects (or bounding-boxes thereof) into *window* space.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [gluUnProject()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml).